# Move Terabytes of data from one container to another in ADLS (Azure Data Lake Storage)

Tags: azure, bigdata

We have a requirement to move many containers and files within containers from one subscription to another in the Azure realm.

We have tried AzCopy and ADF. The data movement either errors out or takes forever to complete.

Has anyone done a similar data transfer before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned the recommended approach would be to use either Azcopy or ADF. I am sharing a few suggestions and best practices to get a better performance. Hope this helps.

1. **Azcopy:**  To get a better throughput and faster performance, You can increase the throughput of copy operations by setting the value of the [AZCOPY_CONCURRENCY_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-optimize#increase-concurrency) environment variable.
   You could try to set this environment variable to value greater than 1000 because AzCopy uses server-to-server APIs, so data is copied directly between storage servers and does not use your machine's processing power. More Info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-optimize?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#increase-concurrency).

If you still face the issue after follow the above, you could identify the
cause of the failure by analyzing the azcopy logs by using `--log-level`
parameter in the command. Available log levels are: DEBUG, INFO, WARNING,
ERROR, and NONE.

2. **Azure Data Factory** Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-hello-world-copy-data-tool) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=data-factory) article.

**On a side note:** If you want to Copy from Blob Storage to Blob Storage programmatically, you could also leverage the [Data Movement library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json).

If you want to copy through the UI, You could also use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows).

Comment: we have been working with Microsoft and using the Classic Migration tool for this.